# How to get item list in FirestorePagingAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm using FirestorePagingAdapter for showing items from Firestore. Which method is invoked when data is loaded? like FirestoreRecyclerAdapter overrides a method `onDataChanged()` when data is loaded.

```java
FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(options) {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        // Called each time there is a new query snapshot. You may want to use this method
        // to hide a loading spinner or check for the "no documents" state and update your UI.
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        // Called when there is an error getting a query snapshot. You may want to update
        // your UI to display an error message to the user.
        // ...
    }
};
```

What is equivalent of `onDataChanged()` in FirestorePagingAdapter. I've tried `onCurrentListChanged()` but **currentList**'s size is always zero.

```java
@Override
public void onCurrentListChanged(@Nullable PagedList<DocumentSnapshot> currentList) {

                if(currentList.size()==0){
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCurrentListChanged: no data");
                    emptyBoxAnimation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is equivalent of onDataChanged() in `FirestorePagingAdapter`

Is BaseChangeEventListener's [onDataChanged()](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/92965d8727bc7c540c0d25119f6fef9846374906/common/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/common/BaseChangeEventListener.java#L29) method, which has the same name as the one you mentioned in your question. From the coomnents that are present in the class:

> Callback triggered after all child events in a particular snapshot have been processed. Useful for batch events, such as removing a loading indicator after initial load or a large update batch.

Comment: If we use FirestorePagingAdapter for loading chat messages then how it will detect a new message arrival, currently I am using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter which automatically loads new message but it cannot lazy load the data, so we have to use FirestorePagingAdapter . Do you have any solution regarding this?

Comment: @Nainal You should ask a new separate question regarding that topic.